# suspending a kotlin Coroutine does not work with volley

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley, kotlin-coroutines

I wrote following (test) function to talk to the google maps api via volley and with coroutines. Sadly it never finishes when calling it with the suspendCoroutine. If I use the same function, drop the coroutine stuff and implement a "normal" callback, everything works fine. I am kind of at a loss whats the problem here. Is anybody able to help?

Code executes until Log.d(LOGTAG, "AFTERAFTER"), but never reaches Log.d("findNaturalLocations", "Response: " + response)

```
suspend fun testNaturalLocations(tag: Tag, lastKnownUserLocation: 
Location): ArrayList<CLDistanceRequest> = suspendCoroutine { 
continuation ->

    Log.d("findNaturalLocations", "getDistanceAndTimeBetweenLocations")

    var distanceRequests = ArrayList<CLDistanceRequest>()

    val mapsBaseUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/"
    val mapsOutputFormat = "json"

    val location = "location=" + lastKnownUserLocation.latitude.toString() + "," + lastKnownUserLocation.longitude.toString()
    val radius = "radius=5000"
    val keyword = "keyword=Supermarket"
    val name = "name=Supermarket"
    val sensor = "sensor=true"
    val apiKey = "key=API_KEY"

    val finishedUrl = mapsBaseUrl + mapsOutputFormat + "?" + location + "&" + radius + "&" + keyword + "&" + name + "&" + sensor + "&" + apiKey

    Log.d(LOGTAG, finishedUrl)

    val jsObjectRequest = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, finishedUrl, null,
            Response.Listener<JSONObject> { response ->
                Log.d("findNaturalLocations", "Response: " + response)

                var results = response.getJSONArray("results")

                // parse distanceRequests, ommitted for brevity

                continuation.resume(distanceRequests)
            },
            Response.ErrorListener { error ->
                Log.e("Error", error.localizedMessage, error)

                continuation.resumeWithException(error)
            }
    )

    Log.d(LOGTAG, "AFTER");

    jsObjectRequest.setShouldCache(false)
    CLGlobal.getRequestQueue().add(jsObjectRequest)

    Log.d(LOGTAG, "AFTERAFTER");
}
```

Doing the same with a simple callback works flawlessly.

```
var i = 0;
    runBlocking {
        val query = async(CommonPool) {
            i = this@CLTaskList.test2()
        }

        query.await()
    }

suspend fun test2():Int = suspendCoroutine<Int> { continuation ->
    Log.d("TESTTEST", "TEST2 CALLED")
    test {
        Log.d("TESTTEST", "CONTINUATION")
        continuation.resume(it)
    }
}

fun test(completionHandler: (Int) -> Unit) {
    Log.d("TESTTEST", "TEST CALLED")
    completionHandler(1)
}
```

Comment: If it doesn't even reach `Log.d("findNaturalLocations", "Response: " + response)`, then it's not about coroutines at all, because it would reach that line with or without the coroutine being correctly resumed. Your callback simply fails to execute for other reasons.

Comment: Thansk for trying to be helpful, but that is not it. I tested it without and it works, see my original post. My assumption is that the networkrequest is done on a background thread and the result should be delivered to the thread which started the request and probably the coroutine is running on. this thread is still blocked by the waiting coroutine and never gets the result because of that, basically getting a deadlock.

Comment: You didn't show the callback-based code that works. The coroutine isn't running on any thread after it's suspended (that's their reason of existence). If execution reached the `AFTERAFTER` statement, this is where the `testNaturalLocations` call ended with a `COROUTINE_SUSPENDED` return value. If it doesn't reach the log statement within the callback, that means the callback hasn't run. Maybe your wider code is doing something wrong and blocking the UI thread, but that's impossible to tell given the code you've shown here.

Comment: Ah I see, you refer to the second block as the "simple callback", but that's just a trivial code without volley. It doesn't demonstrate anything relevant because you never even suspend the coroutine --- when you call `resume` from within `suspendCoroutine` block, it just returns the result right away, no suspension involved. The fact that you pass a lambda to `test` is beside the point, it's the same as if it were inlined. To demonstrate anything at all relevant you'd have to involve another thread that executes your callback and resumes the continuation.

Comment: Wait.. did you perhaps use `runBlocking` in your GUI code as well, and not just the simple example? Because that would immediately explain it.

Comment: `val query = async(CommonPool) { 
            this@CLTaskList.testNaturalLocations(tags[0], CLGlobal.getInstance().mLastKnownLocation!!)
        }

        runBlocking<Unit> {
            query.await()
        }` Yes I did, see above

Comment: This is the key information for your question, you should put it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you reveal in your comment, this is how you run the query:

```
val query = async(CommonPool) { 
    this@CLTaskList.testNaturalLocations(tags[0], 
         CLGlobal.getInstance().mLastKnownLocation!!) 
} 
runBlocking<Unit> { query.await() }
```

You are close to getting it right, but this piece of code is all backwards:

1. You let the suspendable function run in a thread pool, relieving some worker thread of the duty to block until you get your answer (it wouldn't care if it's blocked);
2. You block your GUI thread with `runBlocking`.

In the correct solution you need none of `async`, `CommonPool` or `runBlocking`, all you need is this:

```
launch(UI) {
    val result = testNaturalLocations(tags[0], 
       CLGlobal.getInstance().mLastKnownLocation!!)
    // deal with the result right here
}
```

Since `testNaturalLocations` is a suspendable function, it's not blocking your UI thread, and when the callback you wrote resumes it, your code simply goes on to the next line, with `result` assigned.